# How to set up Google Cloud Storage Load Balancer to point different domains to specific folders on the same bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, load-balancing, google-cloud-load-balancer

I can't find a way to set up Google's Cloud Storage load balancer's host path and rules to point different domains to their corresponding folders in a single bucket.

I have two domains: **foo.com** and **bar.com** and I have a bucket with two folders in it: `foo/` and `bar/`. I want **foo.com** to serve files from the `foo/` folder and **bar.com** to serve files from the `bar/` folder.

I only see options to point specific domain paths to different buckets (e.g. foo.com/bar/ pointing to another bucket) but not different hosts/domains to different paths in bucket. How can I set up the rules to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show your URL & path configuration?

Comment: It's set to "Route traffic to a single backend" for any path in Host and path rules. Is there some deeper configuration that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the advance feature of HTTPS load balancer and especially the [URL prefix rewrite](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite#modifying_the_url_map).

For that, you need to configure your host and path rules in advanced mode. Then, for the default access (without specific domains), you can redirect (URL REWRITE) to the /default folder of the backend.

[image]

Add host and path, and for foo.com, redirect to the folder `/foo` by rewriting the prefix

[image]

Do the same for bar.

Wait 5 minutes (let the Load Balancer to advertise the POP), and enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you! It works exactly as required but only with the trailing slash. When I go to foo.com/folder (without the trailing slash) it redirects me (301) to foo.com/foo.com/index.html which does not exist. Which is contrary to the default behavior described in the docs with MainPageSuffix enabled: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#examples (no zero byte objects).